# run java project using .sh file in jenkins in mac

Tags: java, linux, macos, shell, jenkins

i want to run a java project in jenkins in mac.i have the following .sh file and its code is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@

${jvmargs[@]}

DIR=$(dirname $0)

args=( "$@" )
javaProps=( )

server_jvmargs=( -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"${jvmargs[@]}" )

XX_HOME="$DIR" 
client_classpath="$XX_HOME/lib/others/*:$XX_HOME/lib/http/*:$XX_HOME/lib/selenium-java-2.37.0/*:$XX_HOME/lib/selenium-java-2.37.0/libs/*:$XX_HOME/lib/TestNG/*:$XX_HOME/lib/mailactivation/*:$XX_HOME/bin"

BIN_PATH="$XX_HOME/bin"
SRC_PATH="$XX_HOME/src"

rm -rfv "$BIN_PATH"
chmod 777 "$BIN_PATH"
mkdir -p "$BIN_PATH"

cd $DIR

 javac \
-cp "$client_classpath" \
-d "$BIN_PATH" \
-sourcepath $SRC_PATH src/com/*.java

java \
"${server_jvmargs[@]}" \
"${javaProps[@]}" \
-Dxx.home="$XX_HOME" \
-Duser.dir="$XX_HOME" \
-cp "$client_classpath" \
 org.testng.TestNG temp-testng-customsuite.xml
```

i set the custom workspace and use this run.sh file in build setup(Execute Shell). But it shows the following error:

```
Started by user Ali Azam JenkinTest
Building in workspace /Users/aliazam/Desktop/App/eclipse/workspace/Training

java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs:    /Users/aliazam/Desktop/App/eclipse/workspace/Training
at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1164)

at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1268)

at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild. java:610)
  at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
 Finished: FAILURE
```

can anyone please help me to solve this problem????

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to create a directory in  /Users/aliazam/Desktop/App/eclipse/workspace/Training.  Check your folder permissions chown 777.

Comment: @duffymo, i also tried by using  chmod 777 "$BIN_PATH"  and the same problem is shown

Comment: Are you the Jenkins server admin?  If not, I'd find them and talk to them about the issue.

Comment: i am not sure about my user. Is there any problem in my code or any suggestions or to check any thing in my classpath or anything related this issue where i have to check??